# Filtered Search with Scope Bar (Split View) in an Array

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, scope, uisearchbar

So I have a Vegetable object that among other properties, has an array foodArray that looks something like this `["Stew, "Salad"]` representing in what recipe a food could be included in and `["Eaten"]` if the vegetable is no longer found in the pantry. So for example:

```
let carrot = Vegetable(name: "carrot", foodArray: ["Stew"])
let tomato = Vegetable(name: "tomato", foodArray: ["Salad"])
let onion = Vegetable(name: "onion", foodArray: ["Stew", "Salad"])
let corn = Vegetable(name: "corn", foodArray: ["Eaten"])
```

and all of these Vegetable objects would be stored in a Vegetable array called `vegetables`.

My question is whether I could use the values of this array to set up a filtered search.

I've already implemented SplitView and set up the search bar and have a table view with a list of Vegetable objects. I want the scope bar to feature the different strings (recipe names) found in the array. For example, "Stew", "Salad", "Eaten" to be scope buttons and when the user searches within the scope button, all the vegetable objects that have that button in the foodArray would pop up.

Currently, my code works fine except for the implementation of my scope. This is the code I have so far:

```
func filterContentForSearchText(_ searchText: String, scope: String = "All") {
        filteredVegetables = vegetable.filter({( vegetable : Vegetable) -> Bool in
            let categoryMatch = (scope == "All") || (vegetable.foodArray == scope)
            return categoryMatch && vegetable.name.lowercased().contains(searchText.lowercased())
        })
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
```

Could someone tell me how to modify this `filterContentForSearchText` function to search through the Array and to have the scope buttons be the different possible values in the array (assuming they are only the three I listed above i.e "Eaten", "Salad", "Stew")? I want to maintain my storyboard split view setup. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `contains` with `filter` inside the `UISearchBarDelegate` method [`searchBar(_:selectedScopeButtonIndexDidChange:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uisearchbardelegate/1624280-searchbar).

```
func searchBar(_ searchBar: UISearchBar, selectedScopeButtonIndexDidChange selectedScope: Int) {
     let food: String 
     if selectedScope == 0 {
          food = "Stew"
     }
     else if selectedScope == 1 {
          food = "Salad"
     }
     else {
          food = "Eaten"
     }
     filteredVegetables = vegetable.filter { $0.foodArray.contains(food) }
     self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: Thank you! Would it be possible to combine two values into one scope? For example, if I wanted two scope buttons: "Eaten" and "Recipe" where "Recipe" contains "Stew" and "Salad"?

Comment: Yep, that's it.

Comment: @ch1maera For that `Eaten` filter is same as like my current solution for `Recipe` you can filter your array this way. `filteredVegetables = vegetable.filter { $0.foodArray.contains("Stew") || $0.foodArray.contains("Salad") }`

Comment: Thanks! Because there are now two filteredVegetables variables would they go in the if/else statements?

Comment: @ch1maera Yes now you need to add filter inside the `if/else` block.

Comment: Got it. Thank you so much!

Comment: @ch1maera Welcome mate :)